# Axis web service client respnose HashMap

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I am trying to consume a web service which returns a Java hash map, following is the code for that

```
        String endpoint =
                "http://localhost:8080/eCWServices/StructSpeech/StructSpeech";

        Service service = new Service();
        Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
        call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
        call.setOperationName(new QName("http://ejb.ecw.com/", "parseNotes"));
        call.addParameter("notes", org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
        call.addParameter("apuId", org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
        call.addParameter("providerId", org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
        call.setReturnType(XMLType.SOAP_MAP);
        HashMap  ret = (HashMap) call.invoke(new Object[]{"","",""});
        System.out.println("Sent 'Hello!', got '" + ret + "'");
```

The returned HashMap is always empty and I think that axis does not support it. Can anyone give me pointers where i can find how to consume a service in jdk 1.4 which returns a hashmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Solved it by returning a byte[] by serializing it to a ByteArrayOutputStream, I retrieve the byte array and convert it back to hashMap on client side.